# Android Studio: Application Installation Failed, Error Installing APKs

Tags: java, android-studio

I am trying to run my Android Studio application in the Emulator and every time I run it, it brings this message:

[image: Error Message]

If I click `OK`, it stays installing apks and makes no progress. If I click `Cancel` it says

> Error installing APKs.

I looked through a lot of similar errors, and have had no luck.

Comment: Hard to offer suggestions if you've tried all similar answers but don't include which similar answers don't help. The emulator has enough available space to install the app?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is common on Some Android Devices. This can resolved by turning off MIUI optimizations from Developer Options in Settings app. Please try as follows .

**In your Device Setting**

```
Settings --> Additional settings --> Developer options --> Turn Off MIUI optimization
```

Or

```
Settings --> Developer options --> Turn Off MIUI optimization
```

Or 
**In your Android Studio ** Disable Instant Run

```
Android Studio > Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem right after I wiped data on my Emulator. I didn't check the Instant Run, Clean project didn't help for me.

I suspected that something went wrong during the installation and Android Studio were not intellect enough to fix it.

So I wiped the data again and restart the Emulator, this time I wait till it's fully boot up. I then ran the project and it's just working again.